# Center Text align for labels

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a label exactly in center of a form with text "It is my Visual Studio application". Now, I have a button click event that changes the text to "My application". But the problem is the alignment gets disturbed as the length of changed text is different from previous one. I tried TextAlign option of label to MiddleCenter. but no luck. Can any one help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will also need to set the width of the label to the length of your longest text, or just to the width of the form.

Comment: and obviously autosize to false before that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

You can even do better: set the label Autosize OFF, and manually stretch the label in the designer to
fill the area that's needed to show the largest text value.
Now if you set the TextAlign to MiddleCenter, you get the effect you want (even in the designer, so you can check it by setting a value in the Text property).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the label autosize to true, put that label inside a frame (or a table cell), and make the anchor properties to none. That way it will be centered always.

Comment: But will it be a good solution, i have number of lables in different places with different alignment property and placing them in each panel will be a bit difficult. Well I know this method already but looking for a better solution. Still many thanks

Comment: So, what is exactly your problem? if not centering the label, can you explain it further? other solutions could involve calculating the length of the label and move it according to the new width.